# How to combine two databases?

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-room

I am asking myself how to best define a new database given two databases.

I have the following two databases

1. `Author` where I save information about authors i.e. `Name`, `Birthyear`, `Country`, `Genre` etc.
2. `Book` where I save information about the book i.e. `AuthorName`, `ReleaseYear`, `Pages` etc

How do I create a new database with the full information about all books and the author? I.e. a `Book_Complete` Database which includes `Author.Name`, `ReleaseYear`,`Pages`, `Genre`,`ReleaseYear` and `Author.Birthyear`, `Author.Country`?

Comment: Presumably  you have tables in one database, not separate databases.  There is no need to create a new "database" or table, when a simple query suffices.

Comment: Why do you want to denormalize your data? Why not just have a `VIEW` or a query defined in your application?

Comment: Basically, I have these create these two tables on my app and want to store the combined version on a server. Or would you suggest another approach?

Comment: The database consisting of two tables as you are showing it, is already good. You will have to think about relations, though. (This is what a relational database is for after all.)  Please read my answer on this. As is, I see there is a genre in the authors table. This is their main genre, I suppose? If you want to work with genres, you will probably want to add a genre table with all available genres and a bridge table to tag each book with one or more genres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically, I have these create these two tables on my app and want to store the combined version on a server. Or would you suggest another approach?

Yes we would. You should have one table per entity, i.e. one for the authors and one for the books. Thus you don't store data redundantly (e.g. the author's name or the book's title), which could otherwise lead to inconsistencies later. You can read up on database normalization here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization or google it.

Now you must decide how to link the tables. One author can write multiple books. Can one book be written by multiple authors? Give both tables IDs you can work with (or find some natural unique key, like the ISBN for the book and maybe name + birth year for the author - the name only will probably not suffice and maybe it won't even when combined with the year).

If one book can only be written by one author, you have a 1:n relation (one book written by one author, one author writing multiple books).

- author (author_id, name, birth_year, country, ...)
- book (book_id, title, author_id, release_year, pages, ...)

If one book can have several authors, you have an m:n relation (one book written by multiple authors, one author writing multiple books).

- author (author_id, name, birth_year, country, ...)
- book (book_id, title, release_year, pages, ...)
- book_author (book_id, author_id)

You can always join the tables, so as to get a combined result.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two tables in a database you can combine them using `JOIN`. Here is SQLite tutorial on how to use `JOIN`.

https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-join/

On the information you provided I assume you can you columns `Name` in table `Author`, and `AuthorName` in table `Book`. You can try something like this

```
SELECT
  A.Name,
  B.ReleaseYear,
  B.Pages,
  B.Genre,
  B.ReleaseYear,
  A.Birthyear,
  A.Country
FROM
  Author A
  LEFT JOIN Book B
    ON A.Name = B.AuthorName
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to go for a single database and having 2 tables in it like

Author Table
AuthorId (PK)
Name
Birthyear
Country
Genre

Book Table
BookId (PK)
AuthorId (FK)
ReleaseYear
Pages

Comment: While I agree they should stick with the two tables and while I consider it a good idea to work with surrogate keys here (as it will be difficult to decide for a unique identifyer for the authors otherwise), your answer would benefit from you explaining *why* you think this is better.